# Can I post my essays here for others to comment?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to improve my English writing and take the initiative to write daily. However I do not have a teacher to mark my work. So can I post my essays here for others to comment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/878/29807 and https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/29807 .

Answer (score 7):

As Chenmuka stated we don't accept critique questions on the site we do however have a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115415/beta-reviewers-reviewing) for people to post work to get feedback.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you read the site guide it states this.  This site has a specific close reason covering requests for criticism.